# Convert date to string with limited precision

Tags: python

I'm using `dateString = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')` on this date: `2012-06-28 16:11:17` which returns `2012-06-28 16:11:17.999771` which for some reason is unparseable by Objective-c. How can I limit the last part of the string to 3 decimal places rather than 6?

Comment: date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]

Comment: Nice, this worked! What does the [:-3] represent? (If you post as an answer, I can accept it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
```

This is [slicing](http://techearth.net/python/index.php5?title=Python%3aBasics%3aSlices) (syntax [from : to(but but not include) : step]):

```
>>> '123456'[:-3]
'123'
>>> '123456'[3:]
'456'
>>> '123456'[1:-1]
'2345'
>>> '123456'[::2]
'135'
>>> '123456'[::-1]
'654321'
>>> '123456'[-2::]
'56'
```

Comment: Are there any catches with this though? Is it possible that my date returns less than 3 decimal places with my code above? If it did, then it would chop off more than I wanted..

Comment: @mohabitar, `datetime(2012,6,28,0,0,0,0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')` -> `'2012-06-28 00:00:00.000000'`

Answer (score 0):

`[:-3]` method looses precision i.e., `'17.999771'[:-3] -> '17.999'` but it should be `18.000`.

To correctly round the time you could [convert `datetime` object to seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279), round them and convert them back. e.g.:

```
from datetime import datetime

dt = datetime(2012, 6, 28, 16, 11, 17, 999771)


secs = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(round(secs, 3)) # round to thousands
print dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
# -> '2012-06-28 16:11:18.000'
```